# type casting from array to string for php function argument

Tags: php, casting

I have the following snippet of code.

```
<?php
$arr = array('str' => 'arr');
var_dump(htmlspecialchars($arr));
?>
```

And has the following output.

```
Warning: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /Users/shodoco/test.php on line 3
NULL
```

I am wondering why I am getting this output. According to the PHP manual [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.casting), arrays are always converted to the string "Array". htmlspecialchars() takes its first argument as a string, and my understanding is the array should be implicitly converted to string "Array". But in this example, I am getting NULL. What happens here?

Comment: The manual also says `[...] in the scope of an expression`. That is if you wrote `"$arr"` before passing the variable. Functions are free to assert their parameters, not obliged to cast them.

Comment: NULL usually indicates there is nothing there no array or empty array

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($yourArray);
echo "<pre>";
```

don't change anything on there, just keep the array as is, i find this the best way of inspecting arrays as strings.

hope that answers your query?